# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Datastore Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Tags: grails

am getting the below error when i run grails app in my local

```
file:/home/schepuri/grails/2.4.4/projects/my-app/plugins/excel-import-0.9.6/lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0-without-w3c.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Datastore Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.doGetSession(DatastoreUtils.java:149)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractDatastore.getCurrentSession(AbstractDatastore.java:141)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.createCriteria(GormStaticApi.groovy:297)
```

Here is my BuildConfig.groovy file

```
 dependencies {
compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.1.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.3.RELEASE'
}

plugins {
  compile (":mongodb:3.0.2") {
    excludes 'grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support'
    excludes 'grails-datastore-gorm'
    excludes 'grails-datastore-core'
  }
}
```

Am i missing any dependency plugins in my buildconfig file or

Comment: where this exception is happening? please show your code. seems that you're trying to use database outside the scope

Comment: No its coming while running a groovy script which is internally calls the service class

Comment: script? what script? how do you call it?

Comment: Hi @IgorArtamonov, Basically I have created one grails script inside "MyProj/scripts" folder and which is internally calling service class method of my project. So when I am running that script it is throwing the above error.
For suppose: i have created LoadUser.groovy script and which internally calls LoadUserService.groovy class. So now when i run the LoadUser script, its throwing the above error

Comment: You could try `YouDomain.withTransaction {}` of course, maybe in some hacky way it will work, but I dont think that scripts from this directory is supposed to be used in such way. It's for customizing build process, not app state like database